# Write xommand in Solaris, Unix

Tags: command, write

Hey guys need a little help here. For example me and my buddies are sending messages on our school computers using write user* pts/** , my question is can the system administrator see on his pc that we are sending messages to each other ? Also are wr able to delete the messages afterwards .tnx

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `write` command doesn't log the message anywhere.

However, the system administrator may have configured it to make logs. If they have, you may or may not be able to find out. If you don't want the administrator to know something, don't write about it on their computers.